# MYSQL Async: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this code.

```
using (var personReader = await personCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while (await personReader.ReadAsync())
    {
        personId = Convert.ToInt32(personReader["person_id"]);

        var contestReader = await contestCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

        using (contestReader)
        {
            while(await contestReader.ReadAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(contestReader["id"]);
            }                
        }

    }
}
```

I am having trouble getting to he next `ExecuteReaderAsync` as I am having an error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Can somebody point to me what's wrong with the code? Tried to close the first reader but having a different error pertaining to reading when datareader is closed.

This is also located inside a loop block.

Comment: why are you using async calls when waiting for them in a loop?

Comment: I'm trying to fireup 11M entries with Multiple SQL connections.

Comment: Here's my scenario, I have an object which contains 8 keys. Before inserting the 11M records to DB, I need to get the keys first for reference table. Are there any fastest way to do this asynchronously?

Comment: I think problem is that you have one connection with personreader and you open another reader on the same connetion before personreader is closed, could you show the code where commands are created

Comment: Yeah. Saw that problem. I added another connection just to cater another datareader but this is not the best way to do it. I have approximately, 6-8 datareaders and its not ideal to create 6-8 connections just to fire it up. MARS, on the otherhand, is not supported in MySQL. (which sucks)

Comment: you might have to reconsider your solution then , maybe using more advanced sql querys

Comment: Yeah. I am probably working on that one right now. I have it now working but performance wise, it's not acceptable.